# How to make same layout for all web pages

Tags: css, html

I am currently working on HTML I want to ask a question about website development.I am developing a website in which the basic layout remains same like menu, side menu etc but only the content changes.Currently I have make separate .html file for all web pages.
Can any one tell me is there a way through which I can make a separate  file having    etc common to all and call it in my html file.I have heard about CSS but it will only change the style and layout.
thanks

Comment: How will you write your HTML _applications_? ASP.NET? PHP? JSP? They  provide a page template (or master page) from what every page can inherit.

Answer (score 14):

If your HTTP ([apache 2](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/ssi.html) and [IIS](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/eced0b89-e052-42ff-baa8-751dd191c3b5.mspx?mfr=true) do) server supports [Server Side Includes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes) then you can just include another HTML file :

```
<!--#include file="header.html"-->

your content

<!--#include file="footer.html"-->
```

no need for a server side language then - just plain HTML

Comment: I don't get it. I have an HTML page like this: http://pastebin.com/Qvk0zFYS and a CSS file that looks like this: http://pastebin.com/KqMq9GaT. How can I set the same layout for a page like this? http://pastebin.com/xR35Ewbw

Comment: doesn't do what it is supposed to do.

Answer (score 4):

This is very big topic to include in just one answer. SO I will give only the logical part.

Separate your template into multiple chunks like:

```
1. header.php
2. leftSidebar.php
4. rightsidebar.php
5. footer.php
```

Now, include these common part on your every page.

For example: `index.php`

```
<?php

    include "header.php";
    include "leftSidebar.php";
    echo "<div>".$thedifferentpart."</div>"; //Change only this part on every other page you will create.
    include "footer.php";

?>
```

<sub>***NOTE:*** This is only a logical part, applying the concept on your code</sub>

Comment: Is there a way from inside the php file `header.php` to see that it has been called by `index.php`? I ask because I have a menu whose buttons appear differently depending on the current page (i.e. I add a class to the current-page and give it different style)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your best bet is a server side language, as Adam said. Absolutely avoid using the old style html frames: they're deprecated, and cause a certain number of problems, both on the programming side and on google optimization.

By using a server side language, you'll still have entire pages, but they will be partially generated by php (or asp) by printing more files into one. For example:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Bye!

Comment: Hi! Can we do the same using Ruby? If yes, how?

Comment: Hi, I don't use Ruby, sorry. Generally speaking though, people building websites with Ruby in fact use Ruby On Rails or similar frameworks. 
Nowadays, another really simple way of building non-dynamic websites and having includes (partials) without using a server side language, is https://codekitapp.com/ and its kit language (https://codekitapp.com/help/kit/) or maybe some other similar application. I use codekit for all the things and also sometimes for kit, and it's fantastic.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet in the long term is to use a server side language like ASP.net or PHP

Comment: hmm thanks. but do you mean that I have to do it seperatly for every .html fle?

Comment: Please see @starx answer below me for information on how you could proceed using php for this objective.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that is possible, strictly through HTML. However, you could use server side scripting like PHP to get it done. What you're talking about is a *template*, and is used quite often. What you would want, is to have your menu items (and CSS) and your header/footer code in separate pages. This way, if you make changes to the menu, or header/footer, it would be reflected in all the pages (written with PHP) you have scripted with the template method.

You would need the menu.html, header.html and footer.html in a place accessible by your main page code. That is, you would use the template method to write the content of your pages.

A psuedo code example in PHP would be like such:

```
<?php
   include('header.html');
   include('menu.html');

    echo "Your main content items here";

   include('footer.html');
?>
```