# Options for using the same header/footer/navigation/etc. across an entire site?

Tags: html, css

This has more or less been answered in various places on the web, but I'm having a bit of trouble turning what I've found into useful information sort of.

I've gathered that there are multiple solutions to this problem (the problem being that an entire website uses the same Header and the same navigation and the same footer on all of their hundreds of pages, but if they want to change it a bit, they would have to manually change every single page).

One of the solutions I've considered is using Dreamweaver templates that will, upon being changed, reflect those changes in every single page automatically...I don't care too much for this solution, however, because it depends on Dreamweaver, and I may not always be using Dreamweaver for one reason or another.  In addition, every single page would have to be uploaded again.  This solution isn't very attractive to me.

Another solution I've found uses PHP scripting services to insert a PHP file (that is essentially the header or footer or navigation layout) into each page.  And when you change the PHP file, the changes reflect in every page.

The most attractive solution I've found so far is mentioned on this stackoverflow question:

[How to make same layout for all web pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9872912/how-to-make-same-layout-for-all-web-pages)

It mentions simply using SSI to include an html page that contains whatever content you would like to remain consistent throughout your sites many pages.  It's the same concept as the PHP solution; a single file that, when updated, the changes reflect on every single page.  Only it seems to be a much cleaner/simpler and easier solution.

Out of the three, the SSI is hands down, my most favorable, but are there other solutions?  Ideally, what I'd like is a solution that allows me to:

- Make changes to a single source file that will reflect on all the pages
- Allow me to view the changes locally without having to upload to a web-server or without having to run a local web server
- Allow me to easily designate a current page in the main navigation

I think that's all that I'm looking for and I can't imagine there isn't a solution that fits what I'm looking for.  The last item, allowing me to designate the current page in the navigation, is something that I have been trying to figure out.  The only way that I currently know to designate a particular menu item as the current page, is to, in the html, assign a class to that particular menu's entry (IE: class of .current to the "Home" page inside it's HTML) and then the CSS style that I've configured for .current will reflect on the page.  But this relies on the menu being on every single page, as I would have to move the .current class to each respective menu item.  As I was typing that out, I actually started to realize several other problems related to my sites structural design...mainly, I haven't thought out how I'm going build the submenu pages, and their content...bah, but that's something I can figure out through some careful thought and planning :P  and it's really unrelated to this question, sort of, I just wanted to throw it out there because it may have been asked, or might prove some useful information ^_^

Thank you very much!

Whoever downrated my question, please fix that.  While I'm sure you think this is a redundant post, and completely useless, I have found my answer to many questions before, only after browsing through SEVERAL of the same or similarly asked questions.  You get slightly different perspectives of a similar problem and slightly different perspectives of possible solutions and THAT is very useful.  In addition, you'll find different examples, if examples are given, which gives you even more resources.  I do not think it's fair to have downrated my question for any reason.  I see this question as only possibly being useful and causing no harm.  Thanks, it's very much appreciated :)

Comment: That's indeed what PHP is for...

Comment: PHP includes will get you through most of what you ask. Also, it is very neat, sexy, easy, etc. You can basically use PHP just for the includes if you are not that experienced and your requirements are minimal. The result will be a php file containing only HTML, or mostly.

Comment: Agreed, PHP is the way I'd go.

Comment: So that's really how it's done on most sites, eh? :\  I must say, I was hoping for another solution.  I really was hoping to avoid PHP on my site almost entirely due to having to upload changes before I try them.  But I suppose I can't avoid PHP forever, and in fact, I do like the idea behind it.  I just enjoyed being able to check my page locally when I made changes.  I guess I'll just have to embrace it though and deal with having to upload it first :P  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

SSI is still your answer. First, it is easy to run a web server on your local system. I would never recommend doing web development without one. Spend 20 minutes getting http://nginx.org/ running and it will fix other problems you are probably having testing your site from the filesystem.

SSI has a lot of functionality other than just includes (learn more about them by googling it.) For example, you can indicate the current page like so:

```
<ul>
<!--# if expr="${REQUEST_URI} = \/" -->
<li>Home
<!--# else -->
<li><a href="/">Home</a>
<!--# endif -->

<!--# if expr="${REQUEST_URI} = \/test.shtml" -->
<li>Test
<!--# else -->
<li><a href="/test.shtml">Test</a>
<!--# endif -->
</ul>
```

Though indicating the current page using JavaScript is reasonable too.

Comment: You know what?  You're absolutely right.  I've set up a webserver before, it's not that difficult, and I could set the root directory of the server to my website's directory easily and when I save it, BOOM...I only need to open it to test it out.  I must ask, however, most everyone here has suggested PHP Inserts.  What is it about SSI that you like over PHP inserts?  Is there anything that SSI can do, that PHP is unable to do or vice versa?  Thanks!

Comment: Good questions. PHP can do a lot more than SSI so most people go with the "kitchen sink" solution. I avoid it for the same reason - I like to stay with the simplest technology needed to solve my problem. The last few years I have stopped using PHP in my HTML documents (the old server-pages style <?php or <% tags) and the clarity of my codebases improved significantly. I still build REST web services using PHP and use Ajax and SSI to integrate them with the main HTML documents. It is a little unorthodox but it works great.

Comment: Then that makes me want to lean towards SSI again as a solution.  Honestly, I still need to learn PHP, but if SSI is simplest and will allow me to indicate the current page, then I see no reason why I shouldn't use it! :)  Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a recommended resource for learning SSI?  I thought I had one but it is more of a cheatsheet for if you already have a good foundation on the basics of SSI.  Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry, I have not found a resource much better the than top google results.

Comment: No worries, sometimes there are guides out there that are far better than others, and I just wanted to check before I start reading whatever I find that looks good :P  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recomend using PHP for this, but maybe you can use JQuery to do this by loading a external page inside a div, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#div-that-will-load-").load('page_contato.php');
});
```

This way you'll need to have the same code for a HEADER, FOOTER, MENU just saved in a different file and simple call it whenever you want.

Comment: it sounds like PHP is the best way to go so I'm going to go with that.  Everyone was very fast to suggest it so that is reassuring.  I was hoping there was another solution, considering that I like the convenience of being able to make changes and check them locally, but If this be the best way, then so be it!  I found this tutorial:
http://www.apaddedcell.com/how-automatically-include-your-header-navigation-and-footer-every-page
which seems to outline exactly how to do this, so I'm going to start following that.  Thanks!