# How to use a layout/template when creating a website?

Tags: html

I am building up a website, basically it contains 7-8 pages. Just want to know that if i have to write the whole coding again & again... like NAVBAR, HEADER, FOOTER and other things?

What I need to do if I want to make some changes? I have to edit code manually for every page?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make same layout for all web pages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9872912/how-to-make-same-layout-for-all-web-pages)

Comment: plz explain m very new o.o

Comment: Please include what *language* you want to write this in: php? asp.net? etc etc

Comment: Could you edit your question to be more clear. Maybe include what tools you are using? For example are you using any framework or language to help or are you only using html? Have you considered simply copying and pasting the code that you need to reuse?

Comment: **ASP.NET:** http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/ui,-layouts,-and-themes/3-creating-a-consistent-look

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you should consider using the PHP `include` statement to avoid having to repeat code through multiple files.

An example is below:

header.php

```
<header>
    <!-- All the code for your header -->
<header>
```

myWebpage1.php

```
<!-- All the head stuff, title, meta, styles, etc. -->
<body>
<?php
    include "header.php";
?>
<h1>My webpage 1</h1>
<!-- On and on... -->
```

myWebpage2.php

```
<!-- All the head stuff, title, meta, styles, etc. -->
<body>
<?php
    include "header.php";
?>
<h1>My webpage 2</h1>
<!-- On and on... -->
```

You can use `include` statements in all your web page files, as long as they are PHP files.

More information is at: http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Hope this helps.